# Image Galleries in Android

Tags: android, image-gallery

I am working on App and i have do following tasks.

1. Take a picture (done)
2. Get its detail (done)
3. Save in the SD card  (done)
4. Save all the detail and file name (file name which i have save in SD card) save in database (done)
5. If there is no Gallery available then user can make gallery and save that pic in that gallery.
6. If already gallery exist user can take new gallery or he can save it in any existing one.

I have completed first 4 tasks now i want that user can save picture in gallery. I don't know how to create galleries and how to save them. Whether i have to save Galleries in SD Card or In Database...

Comment: if you want to create a gallery like other gallery apps means its bit difficult. else you want to create the gallery to view the images you have captured means we have the some open sources.

Comment: i have to take a pic and save in galleries.and i have to add galleries dynamically....

Comment: you mean your own app gallery like views  to view the pictures right ????

Comment: yap it will be like view

Comment: http://evgeni-shafran.blogspot.in/2011/08/tutorial-custom-gallery-circular-and.html  try with this.. just load the images which you have captured to this gallery.. after every capture you have to update it using array list or media scanner code (if load from sdcard directly)..

Comment: As for as i got from this article ..he is adding image in one static on gallery...But i want to make dynamic galleries as much as i want..

Comment: yeah for that . you have to create that gallery from your own folder.. and after every capture you have to add the captured picture into that folder.. then have to scan the sdcard programmatically and have to bind the gallery adapter... everything have to be done in the background. so you after every capture your gallery also get updated.